# ionic package retorna: "Error: Unpublished by drifty on 2015-04-22T14:17:30.006Z"

Tags: ionic

Ao utilizar o `ionic package` para gerar o `app`, é retornado:

> Error: Unpublished by drifty on 2015-04-22T14:17:30.006Z

Não encontrei nenhum resultado na internet que solucionasse isso.

Answer (score 1):

Usando o comando no *CMD/CLI* "`ionic plugin list`", vi que existia o seguinte plugin instalado: "`com.ionic.keyboard`".
Este plugin está descontinuado. Deve-se então remove-lo com o comando: "`ionic plugin rm com.ionic.keyboard`" e reinstalar a nova versão com: "`ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard`"

Deve-se também alterar no arquivo "`package.json`" a linha "`com.ionic.keyboard`" por "`ionic-plugin-keyboard`"

Após isso, reconstruir o app com "`ionic package`" e deverá funcionar normalmente.